# socket.io - error after upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i was using socket.io with the 0.9.16 version and when i upgraded it, io.sockets.socket doesn't work

```
io.sockets.socket(usernames[usr]).emit('event', msg, username);
```

this "socket" doesn't work in socket.io 1.3.5
i have this error

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Property 'sockets' of object #<Server> is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\xamp\htdocs\connexion\test_server_2.js:260:8)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:106:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
io.sockets.connected[usernames[usr]].emit('event', msg, username);
```

Method changed in 1.0